# views_pre_render add class item to a row

Tags: views, 8

When pre-rendering a view row is there a way to add an HTML class into a single row of the markup, allowing me to add a new background colour to the event item highlighting its importance? This is for the calendar module monthly view

For example,

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row this-item-was-added-using-view-views_pre_render"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Below the is the what I have so far.

```
function pnc_views_overrides_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view)
{
      if ((int)\Drupal::currentUser()->id() === 1) {
        foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {
          try {
            $field_result_value = $value->_entity->field_display->getValue();
            if (isset($field_result_value[0]) && (int)$field_result_value[0]['value'] === 1) {
              // add a class to the change the background color to hi-light its importance 
            }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            \Drupal::logger('viewoveride_pnc_cal_views_overrides')->error($e->getMessage());
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inject a class into a single item"? What type of class to you want to inject?

Comment: I have updated the question thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not want to alter some data, you should use a preprocess function for this. Check this out:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables["view"];
  $viewId = $view->id();
  if($viewId == 'my_view_id'){
    $rows = $variables['rows'];
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
      $important = $row['content']['#row']->_entity->get('field_result_value')->getString();
      $custom_row_class = 'views-row-' . $important;
      $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass($custom_row_class);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the current nid of the node that is being rendered in view?

Comment: @purencool, that would be $row['content']['#row']->_entity->id();

Comment: OK, but this does not work on the calendar module and I think that is what is making it confusing. Which is I have not stated anywhere